# Session data being overwritten without consent

Tags: php

I have the below code running and it turns out that the SESSION variable role is being overwritten on each pass with the database output. But how is that as the SESSION variable is not even called!

```
<?php
try { 
    $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM roles");
    while($role = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

       print_r($_SESSION); 
       if($row->role == $role->id){$selected ='selected="selected"';}
       else{$selected ='';}
       echo "<option value='$role->id' $selected>$role->role</option>";
    }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
?>
```

The session variable is defined via this line a few pages before

```
    $_SESSION['role'] = $row->role;
```

Comment: got any funky aliasing/binding going on? This code by itself could not possibly affect $_SESSION in any way.

Comment: You don't have somewhere else that you are setting the variable role to be a reference to `$_SESSION['role']`?

Comment: The session variable is defined on a seperate page via 
  $_SESSION['role'] = $row->role;

Comment: What is `$row`?  Is `$_SESSION['role']` being assigned in a loop?

Comment: $row is a PDO obj when logging in. Not run within a loop.

Comment: I don't see `session_start();` anywhere. @Max

Comment: its at the very start of the file. the print_r outputs that session role is assigned the object on each pass